# How can I protect MCU SWD portf from ESD?

Tags: esd, swd

I have connected two TVS diodes close to header, and Resistor for limiting the current.
Is it enough to protect the ports from ESD or i need to add anything else or correct this schematics?

[image]

Comment: Usually the series resistors alone are sufficient. I would only add TVS if I expect that lots of people will be messing around with the connector after the development phase - for example if it will be used during series production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The direction of D2 in your schematic is incorrect.

You can calculate the resistors for R5 and R6 using the following information:

1. Max injection/clamping current of the IO pin
2. Max clamping voltage of the ESD protection diode at its peak clamping current

The clamping voltage of the ESDALC6V1-1U2 at its peak pulse of 4A is around 12.5V.  So
$$
  R > \frac{12.5 - V_{CCIO}}{i_{INJ}}
$$
where \$V_{CCIO}\$ is the voltage supply of the IO and \$i_{INJ}\$ is the maximum injection current of the IO pin.

A side note: The ESD protection diodes should be placed very close to the entry point of the signals (close to the H4 connector).